# .NET Maui release build crashes but debug build is fine

Tags: ios, crash, maui, release-builds

I have an app (LightWork) that I want to publish on the Apple App Store. The debug build runs and works fine, however, on submission the release build crashes on start up. Here is the symbolicated crash report:

[image]

I tried disabling XAML compilation & setting the same build configuration against the debug. So I can confirm I don't think it has anything to do with XAML or the build configuration.

I have no idea why its failing and its preventing release. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any exception handling, logging or crash reporting setup?  Have you tried deploying a Release build to a device directly from VS?

Comment: I can’t seem to deploy a release build to an iOS device because the certificate and provisioning profile settings don’t change. Meaning that it will only deploy to the store and not the device. I’ve tried exception handling and already have App Center crash reporting but it crashes before any of this is initialised.

Comment: You can try to enable the interpreter on a Release build, and see if that changes anything:`<PropertyGroup>
    <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>`